# Can an inline function of the derived class override a non-inline function of the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, fstream

I am making a class which is inherited from `std::fstream`. I am making a custom `eof()` function. That function returns the value of a `bool internal_eof` variable which is set and reset under slightly different conditions than those of the `std::fstream::eof()`. These conditions are specific to the nature of my application. The value of `bool internal_eof` is determined by other functions which are not shown here. Since the `BufferedFile::eof()` function which I'm defining just consists of a single statement to `return` the `bool internal_eof` varaible, I've decided to make it an `inline` function. I'm wondering, can an `inline` function of the derived class override a non`inline` function of the base class? What does the standard say? What do you more experienced programmers know anything about this? I don't really have time for testing this manually, because the `fstream::eof()` and `BufferedFile::eof()` behave similarly ~85% of the time. There are just some edge cases where this solution is needed, and they are not easy to reproduce. Knowing whether this solution is a viable one is crucial for further development of the project.

```
class BufferedFile: public fstream {
  public:
    inline bool eof() const { return internal_eof; }
    ...
  private:
    bool internal_eof;
    ...
};
```

Comment: You do know that function definition inside the declarations of the classes itself are already `inline`, right?...

Comment: Are they really? Good to know then. Is that dictated by the standard though? If what you're saying is true, it means that in principle there should be no distinction between an `inline` function and non-`inline` function when it comes to overriding.

Comment: Look at your class closely, the definition of `eof()` is already with its declaration **inside the class**... So it is already inline, no need to externally specify again...

Comment: @Ruks Many programmers in the past have put function definitions inside the declarations of the classes, not knowing that the functions were already `inline`, and they expected method overriding with regards to inheritance to work as expected. And it would be *heresy* for `inline` functions to break method overriding, so I should be good.

Comment: "What does the standard say?"  "I don't really have time for testing this".
Discouraging... I usually try my best to help, but ... nah ...

"There are just some edge cases where this solution is needed, and they are not easy to reproduce."

Are they easy to explain?

Comment: I was previously under the impression that you had to explicitly specify `inline` *everywhere* to create an inline function, even inside the class declarations!

Comment: @Galaxy `inline` only tells the compiler to compile the function at **compile-time** to optimize performance, it doesn't make the function *unique in any way to be **not** overridable*... [Proof](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce847b05c62f16be)

Comment: Complete the question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: @Ruks Best explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except `main()` (*It is compiled and **executed at run-time**, so you can't compile it at **compile-time***), all valid **C++** functions are overridable:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base(); // Virtual destructor...
    virtual void example(); // Function is already 'inline' here... So, it is one of the
                            // cases where the 'inline' specifier is redundant...
                            // and similar was found in your class...
};
```

Here, `inline` is a specifier, like `virtual`, and is **not a type** (*nor does it give the function the power to become unique*), so overriding it is not a problem...

```
class Derived : Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived(); // Virtual destructor...
    void example() override;
};
```

See [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) to know more about this *specifier*...

Answer (score 1):

The original intent of the `inline` keyword was a hint for the optimizer that a function/method is preferred to be a candidate for *inline substitution*. However, compilers are free to use inline substitution for any function, even though it's not marked as `inline`.

In modern compilers, `inline` is of less use for optimization, but for informing the compiler that a function (and variable, since C++17) definition may occur in several translation units and it should consider them as the same definition. (See [inline specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline))

Whichever it is, the `inline` keyword is a specifier used by the compiler and is not actually part of a method's signature, and `virtual` methods can be overridden in derived classes as long as their signature is not changed, whether declared as `inline` or not.

Comment: Great answer!   yes